# Datanode in slave isn't working : Hadoop in CentOS

Tags: centos, hadoop

We've created a Hadoop cluster of two machines following these instructions:

http://tecadmin.net/set-up-hadoop-multi-node-cluster-on-centos-6/

with the machines set as follows:

```
hadoop1 = master & slave
hadoop2 = slave
```

When we start the services (`bin/start-all.sh`), all services (including `datanode` for *hadoop2*) initialize.  Everything is well.

But when we check the DFS size (`bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report`), only one system (*hadoop1*) is detected.

We've checked `jps` on both hosts. On *hadoop1*, all services are displayed, whereas on *hadoop2* only `jps` is running.  This means the data node on the slave is not working even though the master shows that `datanode` is starting on *hadoop2* as well.  When we check the logs, there is no `datanode` log for the *hadoop2* slave.

I've tried all possibles explanations including the namespaceID which we get from namename current VERSION and assign it to data node current VERSION.

What could be the solution for this? I use centOS 7, and apache hadoop 1.2.1